# how to read multiple lines using BufferedReader?

Tags: java, objective-c, sockets

I am sending a Text from Xcode (that a user enters on a textView) to java server.
the text may contain more than one line. 
the problem is when receiving the text, only even lines are being read.
here is my code.

server:

```
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while(inFromClient.readLine()!=null){   //infromClient is the buffered reader

                sb.append(inFromClient.readLine());
                sb.append('\n');
            }
            System.out.println ("------------------------------");
            System.out.println (sb.toString()); //the received text
```

client side:

```
           NSString *notecontent=[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.ContentTextView.text];
        NSData *notecontentdata = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[notecontent dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
        [outputStream write:[notecontentdata bytes] maxLength:[notecontentdata length]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're consuming three lines:

1. Check if there's next line
2. Printing line
3. Storing one.

Noted here:

```
while(inFromClient.readLine()!=null) { //1.
    System.out.println (inFromClient.readLine()); //2.
    sb.append(inFromClient.readLine()); //3.
    sb.append('\n');
}
```

Store the line in a `String` and then do what you want/need with it:

```
String line = "";
while ((line = inFromClient.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    sb.append(line);
    sb.append('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is this:

```
while(inFromClient.readLine()!=null){   //infromClient is the buffered reader
    System.out.println (inFromClient.readLine());
    sb.append(inFromClient.readLine());
    sb.append('\n');
}
```

The issue, specifically, is the three `readLine()` calls. Each call will *read another line from the client*. So effectively you're reading a line to check if the client has stuff to send, *reading another line* and printing printing it, *then reading another* and storing it.

What you want to do is store the read line in a temp variable, print it, then append it:

```
String s;
while((s = inFromClient.readLine()) !=null){   //infromClient is the buffered reader
    System.out.println (s);
    sb.append(s);
    sb.append('\n');
}
```